# How to test custom yup validation by jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, yup

I am trying to create unit tests for the custom yup validation method by jest with correct and incorrect data.

```
function nextValueBigger(message = 'Some error') {
  return this.test('nextValueBigger', (value, { path }) => {
    const errors = value.map((item, index) => {
      if (item?.from < item?.to) { return null; } // Successful validation, no error

      return new ValidationError(
        message,
        null,
        `${path}[${index}].to`,
      );
    }).filter(Boolean);

    if (errors.length === 0) { return true; }

    return new ValidationError(errors);
  });
}
```

I tried with creating simulation of validation like this:

```
const data = [
  { from: 1, to: 2 },
  { from: 3, to: 4 },
  { from: 5, to: 6 },
];
```

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  item: Yup.array().of(Yup.object().shape({
    from: Yup.number(),
    to: Yup.number(),
  }))
    .nextValueBigger(),
});
```

```
it('should not found any errors', async () => {
  const result = await schema.validateAt('items', { items: data }
  expect(result).toEqual(true)
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @slideshowp2 The question is how to test it correctly. For some reason, I can't find anything on this topic. Test that I create working not stable.
And when I try to add incorrect data to the test, errors occur in the yup and I don't know how to catch them to make their expected errors.